# Contents of a subfield

Tags: matlab, data-structures, bioinformatics

I need to obtain a list (cell array) of the contents of a single subfield in a PDB file. I have prepared my structure and am now looking for something like

```
resnames = getfield(PS.Model.Atom,'resName')
```

This however only leaves me with the first entry. I need an output similar to the `what` command.

Comment: Could you describe the structure a bit more, preferably give an example with input and desired output? If I try `a.b.c = [1:3]; getfield(a.b,'c')` It nicely returns `[1 2 3]` as expected.

Comment: getfield(PS.Model.Atom.resName) returns a multitude of

`ans =
NAME`

statements. I would only need a list those names which I could put into a cell array. However, `getfield(PS.Model.Atom,'resName'` returns only the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may have something like this:

```
a{1}='s';
a{2}='t';
```

Now calling it like so

```
a{:}
```

will return several times:

```
ans =

s


ans =

t
```

However, if you can wrap it with brackets:

{a{:}}

It will nicely return everything at once:
ans =

```
's'    't'
```

Now `ans` is a cell array.

---

I have been unable to guess your exact structure, but hopefully this solution (wrapping stuff with brackets) still works. If not, you can always just loop through your variable and extract the elements one by one.

Comment: Yup, thank you ! I know I could cycle but both `size` and `length` threw errors.

Comment: @matlab-oh-no Small tip: Never use `length` unless you have to, the regular choice is `numel`. This is because for a 0x1 or 1x0 array the length is 1, but you cannot loop over it properly. Also (if used properly) size and length should have allowed you to loop. As a learning experience you may want to try and figure out why they failed with `dbstop if error`.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct array is not scalar at some point in the tree. Somewhere in the hierarchy you have 1xN struct array, which would give you multiple `ans` outputs like that.  Another suggestion is to use dynamic field names.  Instead of `getfield`, this would be:

```
PS.Model.Atom.('resName')
```

Thus, you could take Dennis' suggestion and form a cell of all stings like:

```
resnames = {PS.Model.Atom.('resName')};
```